# What is the use of void** as an argument in a function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have to implement a wrapper for `malloc` called `mymalloc` with the following signature:

```
void mymalloc(int size, void ** ptr)
```

Is the `void**` needed so that no type casting will be needed in the main program and the ownership of the correct pointer (without type cast) remains in `main()`.

```
void mymalloc(int size, void ** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(size) ;
}
main()
{
    int *x;
    mymalloc(4,&x); // do we need to type-cast it again?
                    // How does the pointer mechanism work here?
}
```

Now, will the pointer being passed need to be type-cast again, or will it get type-cast implicitly?

I do not understand how this works.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling it (remember to enable compiler warnings), and find out?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well I wanted to understand the type casting mechanism(needed/not needed) here.I will try compiling it though i am not looking at the correctness of the code but of the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` returns a `void*`. For your function, the user is expected to create their own, local `void*` variable first, and give you a *pointer* to it; your function is then expected to populate that variable. Hence you have an extra pointer in the signature, a dereference in your function, and an address-of operator in the client code.

The archetypal pattern is this:

```
void do_work_and_populate(T * result)
{
     *result = the_fruits_of_my_labour;
}

int main()
{
    T data;                      // uninitialized!
    do_work_and_populate(&data); // pass address of destination
    // now "data" is ready
}
```

For your usage example, substitute `T = void *`, and the fruits of your labour are the results of `malloc` (plus checking).

However, note that an `int*` isn't the same as a `void*`, so you cannot just pass the address of `x` off as the address of a void pointer. Instead, you need:

```
void * p;
my_malloc(&p);
int * x = p;  // conversion is OK
```

Comment: will this be void do_work_and_populate(T ** result) instead of void do_work_and_populate(T * result)

Comment: @so: No. But be mindful of the possibility that `T` may itself be a pointer type!

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to `void *`, the type `void **` is not a generic pointer type so you need to cast before the assignment if the type is different.

Comment: so while returning frmo the function void ptr will be typecasted automatically to int*??

Comment: there is an implicit conversion from object pointer types to `void *` type but there is no implicit conversion to `void **` type.

Comment: ok so here *ptr( i.e of type void* will implicitly get converted to type of pointer being passed).Correct!!

Comment: Cast may not solve the problem. (assume arch which have `sizeof(int*)<sizeof(void*)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
void ** ptr
```

Here, "ptr" is a pointer to a pointer, and can be treated as a pointer to an array of pointers.  Since your result is stored there (nothing returned from mymalloc), you need to clarify what you wish to allocate into "ptr".  The argument "size" is not a sufficient description.